# How to implement an anamorphism such that it can be build upon any value of the the return type (rather than just the base case)

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I've got anamorphism defined as follows:

```
-- Fixed point of a Functor 
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

deriving instance (Eq (f (Fix f))) => Eq (Fix f)
deriving instance (Ord (f (Fix f))) => Ord (Fix f)
deriving instance (Show (f (Fix f))) => Show (Fix f)

out :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)
out (In f) = f

-- Anamorphism
type Coalgebra f a = a -> f a

ana :: (Functor f) => Coalgebra f a -> a -> Fix f
ana f = In . fmap (ana f) . f
```

I currently have to write a Coalgebra like this:

```
appendListCoAlg :: (ListF' a, ListF' a) -> ListF a (ListF' a, ListF' a)
appendListCoAlg (In (ConsF a as), listb) = ConsF a (as, listb)
appendListCoAlg (In NilF, In (ConsF b bs)) = ConsF b (In NilF, bs)
appendListCoAlg (In NilF, In NilF) = NilF
```

Here, an anamorphism has to be constructed from the "base case" (`NilF`).

I'm interested in whether it is possible to write `ana` such that I can do something list this:

```
appendListCoAlg :: (ListF' a, ListF' a) -> ?
appendListCoAlg (In (ConsF a as), listb) = ConsF a (as, listb)
appendListCoAlg (In NilF, **bs**) = **bs**
appendListCoAlg (In NilF, In NilF) = NilF
```

where I can return a value of type I'm constructing "early".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ana` does not let you do that. You can use [`apo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.2.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:apo) instead (although it's still not as neat as it could be; the `Either` should really be outside).

```
apo :: Corecursive t => (a -> Base t (Either t a)) -> a -> t
```

```
appendListCoAlg :: [a] -> [a] -> ListF a (Either [a] [a])
appendListCoAlg listb (a : as) = ConsF a (Right as)  -- Right: continue unfolding
appendListCoAlg listb [] = Left <$> project listb    -- Left: stop unfolding
```

```
append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
append lista listb = apo (appendListCoAlg listb) lista
```

Comment: Can `apo` be defined in terms of `ana` in the same way that `para` can be defined from `cata`?

Comment: Yes, and it suffers from the same issue as `para` using `cata` of doing redundant work.